# Sort High To Low SQL PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a big problem with the selection of the table. I want to show me from the highest to the smallest, just that it appears to me like this

```
NAME               `POINTS`

John Doe            0
John Doe2           432
John Doe3           64
John Doe4           0
John Doe5           138
```

I want to show from the highest to the smallest and in the database there is someone who has over 432 points just does not show it

```
 <?php 
$query = sql()->query('SELECT * FROM `PlayersData` WHERE `Points` BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 LIMIT 5');
if( $query->num_rows == 0 ) {
    echo '<div class="nores">No records found.</div>';
} else {
    while( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
        $row = (object) $row;
    ?> 
    <div class="row">
                  <div><?php echo $row->SteamID ?></div>
                  <div>
                    <?php echo $row->Points ?>                      </div>
                </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: You need to do `ORDER BY Points DESC` to get _from the highest to the smallest_. (After WHERE, before LIMIT.)

Comment: @jarlh I tried to do this only because it shows me those who have points below 100 having others with values greater than these

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? BTW, why the between 0 and 1000 condition? Don't you want users with more than 1000 points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `ORDER BY`, use `DESC` to get the highest values first.

```
SELECT * FROM `PlayersData` WHERE `Points` BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
ORDER BY Points DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

If the data type isn't integer, `cast` it when ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM `PlayersData` WHERE `Points` BETWEEN 0 AND 1000
ORDER BY cast(Points as integer) DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/F0KUhg9.png online view https://i.imgur.com/txZFQCw.png database view

Comment: I made a typo, 100 instead of 1000, which I corrected when I saw it. Make another try.

Comment: well I want to start everything from 1000 down

Comment: Just what my query does, after the typo correction.

Comment: not work...it looks the same

Comment: Column data type? Should be integer.

Comment: sorry it was from the type of column I put varchar instead of INT

Comment: You should really alter that column data type to integer. Otherwise you will run into problems like this more times. E.g `Points BETWEEN 0 AND 1000`...